# PhpMyAdmin on Laravel 5 Homestead, Windows

Tags: laravel, homestead

I downloaded phpmyadmin to my /Code folder, and then updated my Homestead.yaml file:

```
folders:
    - map: C:\Users\{ myname }\Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
    - map: C:\Users\{ myname }\Code\phpmyadmin
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
    - map: phpmyadmin.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin
```

I updated my hosts file also...

```
{ ip from homestead.yaml}   phpmyadmin.app
```

When I browse to phpmyadmin.app it displays the same site as homestead.app.
I'm using Windows.
Is there some way to restart homestead? How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reprovision your homestead vm with

```
vagrant provision
```

See [Adding Additional Sites](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead#daily-usage)